# github action on pullrequest only from defined branch

Tags: github-actions

how can i run a github action like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    types:
      - pull_request
```

but only when the pull-request is from a defined branch for example from "dev"
something like this would be nice:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    types:
      - pull_request
    from: 
      - dev
```

Cheers and thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `on.pull_request.branches`.

See [the GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) on exactly this matter.

Comment: hi, i think i dont quite understand: the situation is, that i have branch A, B and C. i push when i accept a pull request from B into A, then on.pull_request.branches=A fires. but it is only supposed to fire if i accept a pullrequest from B to A.

Comment: Oh, right. Scroll a bit further down to the "trigger based on head branch" section (below the blue box)

Comment: i am so sorry, but i just cannot figure it out :/ i have this pr: `github-actions wants to merge 1 commit into dev from release-please--branches--dev--components--release-please-action` and i want an action file to run in on the dev branch after i have accepted this pr. i tried: `on.pull_request.branches: ['dev']` and then under jobs: `if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'release-please--branches--dev--components--release-please-action'}}` with no success :/

Comment: In that case, you will have to use `on.push.branches: ['dev']` trigger, and then in the job, add the if condition `if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'release-please--branches--dev--components--release-please-action'}}`

Comment: this is what i thought, but it never gets behind the if statement. when i remove it and make an `run: echo ${{ github.head_ref }}` it echos an empty line. so i guess i need another way to figure what or who accepted this pr?

Comment: To double check what is happening, I suggest dumping the Github Context in a first job just to see the filled values. To do so, you can use `run: echo "${{ toJSON(github) }}"` in a step (this echo should print something like [this](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d)). There, the idea would be to check where the head branch is set (or if it doesn't appear at all).